# Using RPi 2 over WAN with PuTTY and VNC

Tags: remote, vnc, putty

When using RPi 2 via remote internet connection, is there any harm in using both PuTTY and VNC (tightvncserver) at the same time?

Comment: Other than using  `PuTTY` (which implies Windows ;-) No. I use `ssh` and `vnc` simultaneously from `OS X`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There will be no issues.

Linux is a fully multi-tasked environment.  See multitasking at [linfo](http://www.linfo.org/multitasking.html) and [howtogeek](http://www.howtogeek.com/111417/how-to-multitask-in-the-linux-terminal-3-ways-to-use-multiple-shells-at-once/)